# How can I read the SelectedItem of a Listbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I am trying to get the selected text in a ListBox to show in a list box.
I have a button that when I click, will show the text of a Selected item in a ListBox.

I've already tried getting the list box to show the text in a textbox using `Listbox.SelectedItem`:

```
Listbox1.SelectedItem = Textbox1.Text
```

When I do this, I get the error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object variable or With block variable
>   not set.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is somewhat upside-down.
It's not clear whether you want to set a `ListBox.SelectedItem` using the Text of a `TextBox` or you want to set a `TextBox.Text` with the text of the `SelectedItem` of a ListBox.

The code says one thing, the description another. The error you have is probably caused by a null `SelectedItem` (you haven't selected anything).
But, if you want to set a `TextBox.Text` with the `ListBox.SelectedItem` text, you can use the [GetItemText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext) method. This method has a plus, it won't raise an exception if the Listbox has no selected Items (the SelectedItem is `null` (`nothing`)).

```
TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
```

The opposite:
You can use the [ListBox FindString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.findstring) and [FindStringExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.findstringexact) methods to locate an item in the control's collection corresponding to a given string. 
The former finds the first items in the ListBox that starts with the specified string, the latter matches only the whole string.
The search can begin from a specific index. It's not case sensitive.

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.FindString(textBox1.Text, 0)
' or
listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.FindStringExact(textBox1.Text, 0)
```

You can continue the search specifying, as the starting point, the index of the item previously found:

```
private int lboxSearchIndex = -1;

Private Sub ButtonSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSearch.Click
    lboxSearchIndex = listBox1.FindString(textBox1.Text, lboxSearchIndex)
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = lboxSearchIndex
End Sub
```

Setting the `SelectedItem` is like using the `FindStringExact()` method.
Only a full match will set the item, but it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Listbox1.Text=textbox1.text
Let me know its help you